# I want to install React on my computer, but I got this problem I used the terminal on the visual code app I followed more than one method on the CMD

Tags: node.js, reactjs

npm ERR! cb() never called!

npm ERR! This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:
npm ERR!     https://npm.community

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\manaro\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-03T12_10_39_054Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting learn-react/ from C:\Users\manaro\Desktop-React
Done.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with just `npm i react react-dom react-scripts` ? Not sure where your error comes from but let's try simpler.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.